# How to set one pandas dataframe column value based on a 2nd column's value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

**Situation**

I have a pandas dataframe `df`with a column `sentiment_rating`.

| index | sentiment_rating |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-03-20 | .3 |
| 2022-03-21 | -.4 |
| 2022-03-24 | -.7 |
| 2022-03-28 | .6 |
| 2022-03-31 | .2 |

**Goal**

I'm trying to create a new column `status` who's value will be either `positive` if the `sentiment score` is .5 or greater, `negative` if -.5 or less, or `neutral` if between -.5 and .5.

**What I've tried**

I've installed the pandas DataFrame module, and using this `apply` method:

`df['status'] = df['sentiment_rating'].apply(lambda x: 'Positive' if x <= .8 else 'Neutral' if x > -.5 or < .5 else 'Negative' if x < -.5)`

**Results**

I'm getting an `Error message` of `invalid syntax`, which doesn't tell me much.

I don't have a clear understanding of the `lambda` function, and am not even sure if `apply` is the right way to accomplish my goal.

I've also tried testing with this on 2 dimensions: `df['status'] = ['Positive' if x > '.5' else 'other' for x in df['sentiment_rating']]`, and that's returning `Error message`  `TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'`

Any input on my approach and what I'm doing wrong greatly appreciated. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the lambda function into separate function in order to make it more readable. You can use following,

```
def return_status(x):
    if x >= .5:
        return 'Positive'
    elif x <= -.5:
        return 'Negative'
    return 'Neutral'


df['status'] = df['rating'].apply(return_status)
print(df.head())
```

You will get following output

```
        index  rating    status
0  2022-03-20     0.3   Neutral
1  2022-03-21    -0.4   Neutral
2  2022-03-24    -0.7  Negative
3  2022-03-28     0.6  Positive
4  2022-03-31     0.2   Neutral
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> df['status'] = np.select(
        condlist = [df.sentiment_rating > 0.5, df.sentiment_rating < -0.5],
        choicelist = ['positive', 'negative'],
        default = 'neutral'
    )
>>> df
        index  sentiment_rating    status
0  2022-03-20               0.3   neutral
1  2022-03-21              -0.4   neutral
2  2022-03-24              -0.7  negative
3  2022-03-28               0.6  positive
4  2022-03-31               0.2   neutral
```

For `lambda`:

```
>>> df['status'] = df.sentiment_rating.apply(
        lambda x: 'positive' if x > 0.5 
                  else 
                      'negative' if x < -0.5 
                      else 'neutral'
    )
```

But this is unnecessary and slow.

Comment: It' better to use map() method of pandas.Series while working with single column of a dataframe.

Comment: @bmrs I am not sure I follow why `map` is better in this case. I would think it would be worse.

Comment: Execution time using map(custom_function) i.e without lambda function, is lesser compared to using numpy.select() . here the difference in execution time is negligible but for thousands of data it looks more efficient using map() method. And as you mentioned , lambda function performs the worst.

Comment: @bmrs in my testing its `map` is 3 times slower than using `np.select` for 5000 rows, 8.5 times slower for 50000 rows.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a bit longer than what you were trying, but it does the job:

```
def status(series):
  if series >= 0.5:
    return "Positive"
  elif series > -0.5 and series < 0.5:
    return "Neutral"
  return "Negative"

df["Status"] = df["Sentiments"].apply(status)
```